# Importing text data with variable size separators in kdb

Tags: kdb

I want to import a text file where the columns are separated by a variable number of spaces:

```
A    123
B 222
C  211
```

Running this won't work well:

```
f: ("CI"; " ") 0: `$(":myfile")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can strip the excess spaces as you import it:

```
("CI";" ")0:(ssr[;"  ";" "]/) each read0`:myfile

A   B   C
123 222 211
```

This will likely dramatically slow things down though.

Can you fix the data at the source? Why is there variable numbers of spaces?

Comment: It's a small file, this works great for me. How come I don't need to run ssr for space separators greater than 2 characters? It looks like ssr[;"  ";" "] condenses all the variable characters separators to one space.

Comment: One problem though, it looks like my real fields are truncated to the integer part: 2986.0355 becomes 2986f.

Comment: For your first question, see: http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/Slash#converge . You'll have to provide more info about the floating point value issue.

Comment: For the float fields, my record is `"ABC    1945.96640300   A"`. By calling `flip ("SFC"; " ") 0: (ssr[;"  ";" "]/) each read0 \`$(":myfile")` I get this list: `\`ABC 1945f "A"`. So my decimals are gone?

Comment: The only way I can replicate this is by setting the decimal display precision to 4 i.e. `\P 4`. This only affects the displayed value in the console and not the internal FP value. Increase it by setting `\P 8` or `\P 0` for maximum.